# cannot start mysql 5.1 windows service under normal user account

Tags: windows, mysql, service, users

MySQL 5.1 service can start under Local System account or Administrator User account.
But MySQL 5.1 service cannot start under normal user account.

It gives:

```
Error 1067:The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is giving security permissions to normal user on MySQL Data folder.
Here is another simple way to solve the problem.

1. Create a new user group. eg. `MySQL_Admins`
2. Create a new user. eg. `Mysql_user`
3. Add Mysql_user under `MySQL_Admins` group.
4. Add following security permissions to `MySQL_Admins` on MySQL Data folder (you can find it in `my.ini` file)
   Windows XP
   `datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/data"`

   Windows Server 2008
   `datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/data"`

   a. Read & execute
   b. List folder contents
   c. Read
   d. Write
5. Chage Log On as properties for MySQL Service to `Mysql_user.`
   MySQL Service > Properties > Log On > This account > Select `Mysql_user`
6. Start MySQL Service

Comment: Can only one user be assigned the "Log On" property of the MySQL Service? Or can multiple users be assigned this?

Answer (score 1):

To startMySQL service under normal user account, 
user must have permission to start that service.
User should be at least Standard User. 
Restricted user doesn't have sufficient permission to start service.

I  can solve doing following steps:

1. Create a new user group. eg. MySQL_Admins
2. Create a new user. eg. Mysql_user
3. Add Mysql_user under MySQL_Admins group.
4. Edit registry key permission
   a. Give 'Full Control' Permission to MySQL_Admins Group for 
       HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL

   b. Give 'Full Control' Permission to MySQL_Admins Group for 
       HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services

   c. Give 'Full Control' Permission to MySQL_Admins Group for 
       HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB
5. Add following file security permission to MySQL_Admins Group on
   C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1(MySQL Installation Path)
   a. Read & execute
   b. List folder contents
   c. Read
6. Add Full control security permission to MySQL_Admins Group on MySQL Data Directory
   (You can find in my.ini file)
   Windows XP
   datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/"

   Windows Server 2008
   datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL"
7. Chage Log On as properties for MySQL Service to Mysql_user.
   MySQL Service > Properties > Log On > This account > Select Mysql_user
8. Log Off Admin account
9. After Log On again, MySQL Service will be started under Mysql_user User Name.

Answer (score 0):

First step will be to check the permissions: Does the user you want to run MySQL have all the necessary access rights?

Comment: Which are "run as service".